# Velocity without changing any java code. Can I pass a File object?

Tags: java, velocity

I have a Velocity context object $temp which contains a method calls `void MakeFile(File file)`
another method calls `File GetFile(string name)`
How to pass a file object to MakeFile Method?

I can render $temp and get xxx.imp@18x678z
But when I render these
`#set($a=$temp.GetFile("test")) $temp.MakeFile($a)`

It doesn't work.

Comment: Check that your methods are public. Also, you can print some debugging lines like `$temp.class.name`, `$a.class.name`. What does it print?